# what's the meaning of x[:]=y?

Tags: python

I tried to understand `[:]` in the beginning, but I can't find any document mention it. Where is the best place to learn advanced grammar for Python? Google search won't find `[:]`. But I figured it out at the end. I just wonder where is best place to learn Python 'tricks'.

For example:

```
def test(x, y):
    x[:] = y  
    #x = y

>>> a = [0.5,0.6]
>>> b = [0.3]
>>> test(a, b)
>>>
>>> print a
[0.3]  # [0.5,0.6]
```

Comment: You are asking two questions: 1) "what's mean of x[:]=y?" and 2) "Where is best place to learn advanced grammer for python?"  Which question do you actually want an answer to?

Comment: @xi_ well, that dupe target does not have the `x[:] = y` as means of replacing list contents clearly written out

Comment: I am actually ask second question. @ rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you need to search for is *slice*.   `x[start:end:step]` is the full form, any one can be omitted to use a default value: `start` defaults to `0`, `end` defaults to the length of the list, and `step` defaults to 1.  So `x[:]` means exactly the same as `x[0:len(x):1]`.  You can find more information at 
the [Expression section of the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html?slicings), and [section four of the python tutorial might also be helpful](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html).

Comment: Not to mention [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) itself.

Answer (score 8):

`x[:]` means the entire sequence. It's basically `x[from:to]`.

Omitting `from` means, from the beginning until the `to`.

```
>>> numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> numbers[:5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Omitting `to` means, from the `from` until the end.

```
>>> numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> numbers[5:]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Omitting both means the entire list.

```
>>> numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> numbers[:]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Setting `numbers[:]` means setting the entire list:

```
>>> numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> numbers[:] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Keep in mind setting `numbers[:]` changes that list and does not create a new one. The object will still have the same `id()`.

Answer (score 0):

The notation `x[:]` is equivalent to `x[0:n]` where `n` is `len(x)`.  It specifies the range of elements of `x` from `0` through `n-1` inclusive.

When read, a new list, string, or whatever is created, containing the specified range of elements.

When assigned to, the specified range of elements is destructively replaced in the original.  Note that this is allowed for lists, but not for strings.